# How is the following a ring?

Tags: ring-theory

I am copying it directly from Dummit and Foote.

> A function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to have *compact support* if there are real numbers $a,b$ (depending on $f$) such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\notin[a,b]$ (i.e., $f$ is zero outside some closed bounded interval). The set of all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with compact support is a commutative ring without identity.

I didn't understand how is it a ring. I mean if say $f$ has support $[1,2]$ and $g$ has support $[3,4]$, then $f+g$ will have support $[1,2]\cup[3,4]$ which is not of the form $[a,b]$. 
Also, I didn't understand why wouldn't the given ring have an identity?

Comment: $[1,4]$ will be a support, as will $[-100,42]$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry, I didn't get your point.

Comment: An interval of support does not have to include *only* those points.where the function is nonzero.  If $f$ is supported on [1,2] and $g$ is supported on [3,4], then $f+g$ has [1,4] as an interval of support, so it satisfies the definition.

Comment: We say that a function has compact support  if it is $0$ **outside** some interval $[a,b]$. But it is allowed to be $0$ at many places inside $[a,b]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function $f+g$ has compact support because, for example, it is $0$ outside the interval $[-100,42]$. So there **is** a closed interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(x)+g(x)=0$ outside the interval $[a,b]$.

As for the lack of a multiplicative identity, it is not hard to show that such an identity must be the function that is identically $1$. This function does not have compact support.

Comment: Intuitively it's clear to me that the Identity cannot have compact support. But can you please give a little more rigorous explanation? Also I am still unclear the point you are trying to make about the support of the function.

Comment: Does the fact that the identity function doesn't have a compact support come from analysis? What property of the sets are we using?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x)=x^2+1$ on the interval $[-1000,1000]$ and $0$ outside the interval. If our ring had a multiplicative identity $h$, then we would have $f(x)h(x)=f(x)$ on the interval, so $h(x)=1$ on $[-1000,1000]$. Similarly, $h(x)$ would have to be $1$ on the interval $[-1000000,1000000]$, and so on, so it would have to be $1$ everywhere. But the function that is $1$ everywhere does not have finite support, so is not in our ring.

Answer (score 1):

I just post my response for the sake of completeness.

Suppose that $f$ and $g$ have compact support on $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$ respectively.

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [a,b] \\
  g(x) &= 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [c,d] \\
  (f+g)(x) &= 0 \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus ([a,b] \cup [c,d])
\end{align*}

Then $f+g$ has compact support on $[\min\{a,b\},\max\left\{ c,d \right\}]$.  I think commutativity is trivial.

Suppose we have an idenetiy element $g$ in the ring of functions with compact support.  Since $fg:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined by $(fg)(x) = f(x) g(x) \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, the identity element should satisfy $(fg) = f$ forall $f$ in the given ring.  We suppose that $f \ne 0$.  i.e. $\exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x_0) \ne 0$.

\begin{align*}
  f(x) g(x) &= f(x) &\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\
  f(x) (g(x) - 1) &= 0 &\quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \\
  g(x) &= 1 &\quad \mbox{ if } f(x) \ne 0
\end{align*}

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, we can construct $f_x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by

\begin{equation*}
  f_x(t) =
  \begin{cases}
    x & \mbox{if } x = t \\
    0 & \mbox{if } x \ne t. \\
  \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

This forces $g(x) = 1 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, so $g$ is not in the given ring.  Contradiction.  Hence the ring has no identity element.

Answer (score 0):

#Here f(x)=0 for x doesn't belong to [a,b].
Let R be the set of all such functions f.
Then (f+g)(x)= f(x)+g(x)=0+0=0.
Similarly other axioms of commutativity can be proved.
Now point is R which is the set of all such functions f(x)=0, it will not contain identity because f(x).g(x)=0.0=0 for all f,g belongs to R.
So the ring R will not contain any unit element because product of any two elements of R is 0.
So there doesn't exist any identity.
Hence, here the ring R is a commutative ring without identity #.**strong text**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).